# Issues pushing data with NA values to Oracle Database with dbWriteTable using R

Tags: r, oracle, na, rjdbc

I am having issues with pushing data with `NA` values in Oracle using the `dbWriteTable()`, which comes from R's `DBI` package. When I try to upload this data frame to the desired oracle database, I get an error message saying:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
>
> execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (NaN)

I noticed that when I upload the first row of this data frame, I have no problems, though if I try to upload two or more rows in the data frame, I get this error message. There are no `NaN` or `Inf` values in this data frame. There are only character and numeric variables and certain numeric variables contain `NA` values.

| X1 | X2 |
| --- | --- |
| NA | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |

The table above is an example of a table that will return the error message. If I were to upload only the first row of this table, everything works properly, and the first row is outputted into the Oracle database.

My thought is that there is a bug in the `dbWriteTable()` function that I cannot get around by continuing to use it. Does anyone know of a way that I can fix this issue, or if there are any other methods that I use to complete my task?

Code:

```
dbWriteTbale(conn = jdbcConnection,name = "test", value = test, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE, overwrite=FALSE)
```

My session info is below.

> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
>
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)

Comment: Usually NA is replaced with NULL automatically.  I don't know why that isn't working here. Can you replace the NA's with a number that won't otherwise be in the table, like -1?  Then after dbWriteTable you could replace them with null using SQL.

Comment: Are you running division somewhere in your calculations? How did you check for `Inf` and `NaN`? Don't feely on visual, human inspection. Try converting with: `df[is.na(df)] <- NA`. Also, check if the destination column in table allows `NULL` values.

Comment: There are no Inf or NaN values in this data frame. I replicated the error with the sample data frame in this post, and it only has 1 value that I manually created as an NA value. I am just confused why this issue could be happening, because from what I understand, I should not be having this problem. I can upload the first row and the first row of data looks perfect in the Oracle data base, though when I try to upload two or more rows, I get this error.